# creating link_to using regex from a comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to create a helper that finds any thing that starts with a # that has numbers afterwards separated by spaces, then remove the #, and turn it into a link.

However I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, right now the comment is appearing blank.

How can I do this correctly?

So far I have:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def linkhelper (comment)
        link = comment.to_s.gsub (/a?#\d.*\d/)
        if Post.friendly.exists?(@link)
            boardid = self.board_id
            postid = link
            link_to "#link", boardid.postid, :anchor => link
        elsif Reply.exists?(:pid => @link)
            boardid = self.board_id
            postid = reply.link.post_id
            link_to '#link', boardid.postid, :anchor => link
        else '#link'
        end
    end
end
```

In my view:

```
<% linkhelper(post.comment) %>
```

**Update:**
Currently my site is set up like this: board has many posts, and each post has many replies. When a post is made it checks what the highest `pid` is between all posts and replies for that board, and sets it `maximum pid + 1`.

What I'm trying to do is:

match `#123`, remove the `#`

If it matches any `Post.pid` get `post.board_id`, replace `#123` with a `link_to #123, board_id/123`.

elsif if it matches any Reply.pid get `reply.post_id` and `reply.board_id`. replace #123 with `link_to #123, board_id/post_id#123`.

else just put `#123`.

**The code I ended up using:**

```
def linkhelper(comment)
  comment.to_s.gsub (/#(\d+)+/) do |match|
    slug = $1.strip
    if (post = Post.friendly.find_by(pid: slug))
      link_to ">>#{slug}", "#{post.board_name}/thread/#{slug}##{slug}"
    elsif (reply = Reply.find_by(pid: slug.to_i))
      link_to "##{slug}", "#{reply.board_name}/thread/#{reply.post_pid}##{slug}"
    else
      "##{slug}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `post.link.exists?` supposed to do? Also, why does your method have both `post` and `@post`?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?  I am guessing that either post or reply is actually a collection but I would need to see more code.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Sorry I updated my question with fixed code.

Comment: You are calling gsub on "link" which requires 2 arguments or it returns an enumerator. Also your regex is wrong for what you described. You are looking for something like `.gsub(/a#([\d\s]+)/, '\1')`. Then what do you mean by `#link`?  Are you trying to do variable interpolation? There is a lot wrong with this code.

Comment: @MichaelPapile You're right, I really don't know what I'm doing. This is probably a completely wrong approach. By #link I'm trying to give link_to's as what the user entered, but thats obviously not the right way to do it.

Comment: Try doing one thing a time. Start up IRB and assure that you can get the gsub regex to output what you want as it is the crux of your code.  From what you described a post reference looks something like `a#1234 56` and you want that to be `123456` right? You can test that all in IRB.

Comment: Please show an example of what you're trying to match and what you expect the results to be.  That will help craft the correct regex.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I updated my post with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be close to what you're trying to do:

```
def linkhelper(comment)
  link = comment.to_s.gsub (/#(\d+)\s+/) do |match|
    slug = $1.strip
    if (post = Post.friendly.find_by(id: slug))
      link_to "##{slug}", "#{post.board_id}/#{slug}"
    elsif (reply = Reply.friendly.find_by(pid: slug.to_i))
      link_to "##{slug}", "#{reply.board_id}/#{reply.post_id}##{slug}"
    else
      "##{slug}"
    end
  end
end
```

This uses `gsub` with a block to allow you great control over what gets replaced, so the `link_to` should contain the link that you expect.

Comment: I tried this code, it seems like the regex isnt finding it properly so I switched to using `/^#.*$/` to test. This finds it but returns the `else` statement.

Comment: I ended up using /#(\d+)+/ for the regex plus some other minor changes, and that works. However I still can't get anchors working?

Comment: What do you see for the anchor?  I just updated the answer with an explicit anchor in the `link_to` path for the reply `link_to`.  Maybe that'll work better?

Comment: Great Idea, that worked. I also edited my question to show the final code I'm using.